# How do I make 2 images a side-by-side split image in CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

How do I make 2 images a side-by-side split image in PhotoShop CS6?

Comment: Double the width and paste the 2nd image in.

Comment: there is no magic option that will do this for you, you have to do it yourself. wutnaut is correct

Answer (score 1):

Go to the image menu and edit the *Canvas* size (not the image size). You will see a grid of boxes 3x3, choose the center left *or* center right box, uncheck "relative" and set the width to 200%, leave the height at 100%.

Paste the second image as a layer and move to suit.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration @horatio. If I had Photoshop in front of me, I would have included more detail.